# How to create excel file in web app project folder ,but i getting the NullpointerException?

Tags: java, excel, jsp, servlets

```
  public class ExcelSheetController extends HttpServlet implements ServletContextListener
    {

        static File appHome;
        static File customerDataFile;

        @Override
        public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   /* I getting the Apache tomcat folder of web-app and also adding the context path which is  written in web.xml folder{ <context-param>
    <param-name>MyAppHome</param-name>
    <param-value>com/excelsave/</param-value>
</context-param>} */

String  filePath = "C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.5/webapps"+getServletContext().getRealPath("MyAppHome") + File.separator+"udaanmasterdatabase.xls";
            System.out.println(filePath+"  GGGGGGGGGG");    
            appHome = new File(filePath);
            File customerDataFile = new File(appHome, "udaanmasterdatabase.xls");
        }

           protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);    
                 if(session!=null)
                 { 
       try {
                         int rownum = 0;
                          //Create a blank sheet
                            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                           HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
                          shadeAlt(sheet);
                          HSSFCellStyle my_style = workbook.createCellStyle();
                         /* We will now specify a background cell color */
                           my_style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.FINE_DOTS );
                            my_style.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.BLACK().getIndex());
                            my_style.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor.SKY_BLUE().getIndex());
                                 Row row = sheet.createRow(1);
                           for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                            {
                             Cell cell = row.createCell(i);
                           cell.setCellStyle(my_style);
                       switch (i) {
                            case 3:
                                cell.setCellValue("Drive Detail");  
                                break;

                            default:
                                cell.setCellValue("");  
                            }
                            }
                         /*  row.createCell(10).setCellValue("Selection of Student Detail");*/
                           HSSFCellStyle my_style1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
                            my_style1.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.FINE_DOTS );
                            my_style1.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.BLACK().getIndex());
                            my_style1.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor.GREEN().getIndex());
                             Cell cell1 = null;
                            /* cell1 = row.createCell(10);
                             cell1.setCellValue("Selection of Student Detail");*/

                                  for(int i=10;i<85;i++)
                                  {
                                       cell1 = row.createCell(i);
                                    cell1.setCellStyle(my_style1);

                                    switch (i) {
                                    case 10:
                                        cell1.setCellValue("Selection of Student Detail");
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        cell1.setCellValue(""); 
                                        break;
                                    }
                                  }

                                  HSSFCellStyle my_style2 = workbook.createCellStyle();
                                  my_style2.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.FINE_DOTS );
                                my_style2.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.BLACK().getIndex());
                                my_style2.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor.BLUE_GREY().getIndex());
                              Row row1 = sheet.createRow(2);

                                 for(int i=0;i<86;i++)
                                 {
                                     Cell cell2 = row1.createCell(i);
                                        cell2.setCellStyle(my_style2);
                                     switch (i) {
                                    case 0:
                                         cell2.setCellValue("Sno");     
                                        break;

                                    case 2:
                                         cell2.setCellValue("Drive Location");
                                        break;
                                    case 4 :
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Date of Interview");
                                        break;

                                    case 6:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Selected By");
                                        break;

                                    case 8:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Mode of Selection");
                                        break;

                                    case 10:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Student Id");
                                        break;

                                    case 12:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Student first Name");
                                        break;

                                    case 14:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Student Last Name");
                                        break;


                                    case 16:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Qualification");
                                    break;

                                    case 18:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Course Applied");
                                        break;

                                    case 20:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Joining Course");
                                        break;

                                    case 22:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Ending Course");
                                        break;

                                    case 25:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Place of Training");
                                        break;


                                    case 30:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Bank Account Number");
                                        break;


                                    case 34:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Travel Expense");
                                        break;


                                    case 38:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Medical Insurance Number");
                                        break;


                                    case 42:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Medical Insurance Transfer from");
                                       break;

                                    case 46:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Medical Insurance from");
                                        break;

                                    case 50:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Medical Insurance to");
                                        break;

                                    case 54:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Reason Leaving of Institue");
                                        break;

                                    case 58:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Placement Status");
                                        break;

                                    case 62:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Appointment Letter Received");
                                        break;

                                    case 66:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("First Month Salary Status");
                                        break;

                                    case 70:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Second Month Salary Status");
                                        break;

                                    case 74:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Third  Month Salary Status");
                                        break;

                                    case 78:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("Book Returns Leaving Institute");
                                        break;



                                    default:
                                        cell2.setCellValue("");
                                        break;
                                    }

                                 }



                                Row row2 = sheet.createRow(3);
                                row2.createCell(0).setCellValue(1);

                               row2.createCell(2).setCellValue(lgbean.getDrivelocation());


                                row2.createCell(4).setCellValue(datinter);


                                row2.createCell(6).setCellValue(lgbean.getSelectprocedure());


                                 row2.createCell(8).setCellValue(lgbean.getModeselection());


                                 row2.createCell(10).setCellValue(lgbean.getStudid());

                                 row2.createCell(12).setCellValue(lgbean.getFirstname());


                                 row2.createCell(14).setCellValue(lgbean.getLastname());


                                 row2.createCell(16).setCellValue(lgbean.getQualification());


                                 row2.createCell(18).setCellValue(lgbean.getCourseoffered());


                                 row2.createCell(20).setCellValue( join_date );


                                 row2.createCell(22).setCellValue( end_date);


                                 row2.createCell(25).setCellValue(lgbean.getPlacetraining());


                                 row2.createCell(30).setCellValue(lgbean.getBankaccntno());


                                 row2.createCell(34).setCellValue(lgbean.getTravelexpense());


                                 row2.createCell(38).setCellValue(lgbean.getMedicalinsuranceno());


                                 row2.createCell(42).setCellValue(lgbean.getTransferto());


                                 row2.createCell(46).setCellValue(medicaldatfrom);


                                 row2.createCell(50).setCellValue( medicaldatto);



                                 row2.createCell(54).setCellValue(lgbean.getLeavinghostel());


                                 row2.createCell(58).setCellValue(lgbean.getPlacementstatus()); 


                                 row2.createCell(62).setCellValue(lgbean.getAppoint_letter()); 


                                 row2.createCell(66).setCellValue(lgbean.getSelectmonth1()); 


                                 row2.createCell(70).setCellValue(lgbean.getSelectmonth2());


                                 row2.createCell(74).setCellValue(lgbean.getSelectmonth3());


                                 row2.createCell(78).setCellValue(lgbean.getBook_returns());



                   try {


   // file save in the com/excelsave folder in my web-app


                       File customerDataFile = new File(appHome, "udaanmasterdatabase.xls");
                              FileOutputStream out =
                                            new FileOutputStream(customerDataFile);
                                    workbook.write(out);
                                    out.close();
                                    System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                    RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.do");
                    rd.forward(req, resp);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     resp.sendRedirect("logOut.do");
                 }


        }


        private void shadeAlt(HSSFSheet sheet) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
            // Condition 1: Formula Is   =A2=A1   (White Font)
            ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("MOD(ROW(),2)");
           PatternFormatting fill1 = rule1.createPatternFormatting();
          fill1.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.index);
          fill1.setFillPattern(PatternFormatting.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
              CellRangeAddress[] regions = {
                    CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:GG1000")
            };

          sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule1);
         /* sheet.createRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue("Shade Alternating Rows");*/
            sheet.createRow(1).createCell(1).setCellValue("Condition: Formula Is  =MOD(ROW(),2)   (Light Green Fill)");
            }
        @Override
        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

    }
```

/*
  I want the save of my excelfile in my web application com/excelsave folder,but i am not getting the excelfile there.so please suggest me what other approach i follow.I getting the NPE in this part {  String    filePath = "C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps"+getServletContext().getRealPath("MyAppHome") + File.separator+"udaanmasterdatabase.xls"}*/

Comment: please paste relevant part of your code where you are getting null pointer exception along with the stack trace.

Comment: As for the NPE: _where_ do you get it? I mean which line - and please _don't_ just tell us the line number.

Comment: String filePath = "C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/webapps"+getServletContext().getRealPath("MyAppHome") + File.separator+"udaanmasterdatabase.xls"

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this link:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/

It explains the entire procedure and I think your problem will also be solved.

Comment: Yes ,absolutely i run the localhost server save the my file in my local system but this web app project on the server the excel file automatically generate in the web app folder and then after that i read  and wrute the excel file  and automatically save in download folder